# CSS not being applied correctly and it looks wrong

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to apply styles to my template,

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Email Scrapper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
            <form class="card card-sm" action="{% url 'scrap' %}" method="GET">
                <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
                    </div>
                    <!--end of col-->
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" placeholder="Search topics or keywords" name="q" id="InputSearch" value="{{ q.get }}"
                        aria-describedby="searchHelp">
                    </div>
                    <!--end of col-->
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="search>Search</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--end of col-->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--end of col-->
      </div>                      
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    background:#ddd;
}

.form-control-borderless {
    border: none;
}

.form-control-borderless:hover, .form-control-borderless:active, .form-control-borderless:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, the following thing appears:

[Image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHXFe.png)

When it should be more like this:

[This should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dKle.png)

Before it worked, but when I applied some code of my own it suddenly stopped working. This code is running in Django and python.

Comment: If you sure you've done the styling and linking correctly.Try to hard refresh ctrl+shit+r

Answer (score 1):

1: Make sure to add bootstrap link if you are using bootstrap

2: you forgot to put double quotes (") after  type="search

```css
background:#ddd;
}
.form-control-borderless {
    border: none;
}

.form-control-borderless:hover, .form-control-borderless:active, .form-control-borderless:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Make sure to add bootstrap link if you are using bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Email Scrapper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                            <form class="card card-sm" action="{% url 'scrap' %}" method="GET">
                                <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" placeholder="Search topics or keywords" name="q" id="InputSearch" value="{{ q.get }}"
                        aria-describedby="searchHelp">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto">
                                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="search">Search</button>
                                        <!-- Here you forgot to put double quotes (") after  type="search -->

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```